# 0/2 nodes are available....2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: kubernetes

I installed thanos using bitnami's helm chart.

After installing prometheus with Helm Chart

Likewise, minio was deployed together while installing thanos with Helm Chart.

The deployed minio pod is in Pending state

`0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.`

Problems arise.

kubectl get pvc check result is Pending status

`no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set`

This happens.

How to build pv in this situation...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you used a pvc in the pod where that pvc is not bound to any pv. You can either do dynamic provisioning (at that time, pvc will create a pv for you as far the requirements), or you can manually create a pv.

For dynamic provisioning can see this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/).
For pv [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/)